# Got "Access is denied" when I tried to rename the computer

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "newname" -DomainCredential CWQWTQ1J\Administrator
```

CWQWTQ1J is computer name and "Administrator" is the username. I am trying to change the name of the local computer. When I run this cmdlet it throws me an error i.e Access is denied. Is there anything I am missing? It will be grateful if someone helps me. [image]

Comment: Run the PowerShell console _as administrator_ by right-clicking and selecting "Run As Administrator". This will run an elevated session.

Comment: yes, I am running it in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the computer is joined to a Domain you need to specify an account on the Domain (with suitable permissions) in `DomainCredential`, the local administrator account will not work here.

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "newname" -DomainCredential "Domain\Administrator"
```

If the computer is a workgroup computer (not part of a domain), you do not need to specify credentials. The account you run PowerShell with will just needs to be a Local Administrator.

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "newname"
```

Comment: Yes, it is joined to the domain. I tried renaming even with my domain credentials, but it is throwing same error.

Comment: Do I have to be an admin to rename the computer which is joined to the domain?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a Domain admin account (although that account will have permissions to pretty much everything), you need to have write access to the computer object for the computer you are trying to rename. This access is not normally delegated to a regular user account.

Comment: Can you tell how to find out whether I have write access to the computer object and can you tell how to provide access so that I can rename the computer? Thank you.

Comment: AD Permissions are set by the System Administrator and will change be dependant on how your individual Domain is setup, I cannot advise on this as I do not know about your domain, you'll need to speak with your sysadmin about those permissions. Once you have the required permissions the commands above will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run powershell as admin. If using a remote session run as a domain admin.

```
# enter domain admin when prompted. This stores them in a variable creds
$Creds = get-credential 

#rename the PC passing the saved credential object:
rename-computer -newname 'pcNewName' -domainCredential $Creds
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My situation was that my account worked locally, but not via a PS Session even though I was running powershell with my admin creds. With domain credential specified the rename stopped returning access denied.